# draw two shape with TikZ in one line

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I draw picture in TikZ like this?
[image]

Comment: yes i can draw only one shape  but i do not know  how put two or more shape in one line.

Comment: It depends on how you draw one shape to draw two shapes. The easiest might be just to use two separate TikZ pictures side by side.

Comment: @user78318 Please show the code for one of the pictures

Comment: Excuse me I do not know English  well. i use this code.\clip (0,0) circle (1);
            \fill[red] (-1,0) rectangle (0,1);
        \fill[green] (0,0) rectangle (1,-1);‎
          \fill[blue] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);‎
            \fill[blue] (0,0) rectangle (-1,-1);‎
                 \draw (0,0) circle (1);‎
 \draw [very thick,-> ] (0,0) -- (-.6,.6);‎

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in one comment it is possible to draw both pictures in a separate TikZ environment. I have written the following code to produce the two desired pictures:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  % First circle
  \begin{tikzpicture}[very thick]
    % draw each arc, rotated by the value stored in \a, filled with the color \c
    \foreach \a/\c in {0/blue!50,90/red,180/blue!50,270/green}
        % arc from 0 degrees to 90 degrees
        \draw[fill=\c,rotate=\a] (0mm,0mm) -- (20mm,0mm) arc (0:90:20mm) -- cycle;
    % arrow 
    \draw[-latex,rotate=135](0mm,0mm) -- (15mm,0mm);
  \end{tikzpicture}

  % Second circle
  \begin{tikzpicture}[very thick]
    \foreach \a/\c in {0/red,45/blue!50,90/red,135/blue!50,180/green,225/blue!50,270/green,315/blue!50}
        \draw[fill=\c,rotate=\a] (0mm,0mm) -- (20mm,0mm) arc (0:45:20mm) -- cycle;

    \draw[-latex,rotate=67.5](0mm,0mm) --(15mm,0mm);
  \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

This code produces the following output:[image]

I've used the foreach loop to draw the filled arcs separately, each with its own color. The arcs are rotated by the angle `\a` and have the color `\c`. Of course the colors and the arrow shape can be adjusted afterwards.

Comment: Why did you load `inputenc`?

Comment: Well, I admit that it isn't really needed for the MWE, but I like to specify the encoding in every file I create, since I made the experience that an unspecified encoding could lead to troubles.

Comment: thanks Simon M. Laube  when I run your code the second circle place "below" of first circle. how solve this ?

Comment: Remove every space between the two tikzpicture environments. The blank line is interpreted as a paragraph ending and that will be the reason for your problem.

Comment: If that still doesn't help you could use one tikzpicture environment only and paste the code from the second one into the first. You will have to change the origin of the second circle accordingly